# Release memory for Pycuda

Tags: python, cuda, pycuda

How do I release memory after a Pycuda function call?

For example in below, how do I release memory used by a_gpu so then I will have enough memory to be assigned to b_gpu instead of having the error as below?

I tried importing `from pycuda.tools import PooledDeviceAllocation` or `import pycuda.tools.PooledDeviceAllocation` hoping to use the free() function but they both result in error when importing `ImportError: cannot import name 'PooledDeviceAllocation' from 'pycuda.tools' (D:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pycuda\tools.py)` and `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pycuda.tools.PooledDeviceAllocation'; 'pycuda.tools' is not a package`.  If it should work on newer version of Pycuda, but just my version of Pycuda is too old, is there any other way to release memory in my version or older version of Pycuda?  I hope the upgrade of Pycuda to be the last resort as my NVidia card is as old as 2060 series and in case the new version of Pycuda does not support my old card.

Thanks a lot in advance.

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda
import pycuda.autoinit
from pycuda.compiler import SourceModule
import os

_path = r"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\Hostx64\x64"

if os.system("cl.exe"):
   os.environ['PATH'] += ';' + _path
if os.system("cl.exe"):
   raise RuntimeError("cl.exe still not found, path probably incorrect")

import numpy as np

a = np.zeros(1000000000).astype(np.float32)
a_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(a.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(a_gpu, a)

mod = SourceModule("""
  __global__ void func1(float *a)
  {
    a[0] = 1;
  }
  """)
      
func = mod.get_function("func1")
func(a_gpu, block=(1,1,1))

a_out = np.empty_like(a)
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(a_out, a_gpu)
print (a_out)

# Memory release code wanted here

b = np.zeros(1000000000).astype(np.float32)
b_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(b.nbytes)
cuda.memcpy_htod(b_gpu, b)

mod = SourceModule("""
  __global__ void func2(float *b)
  {
    b[1] = 1;
  }
  """)
      
func = mod.get_function("func2")
func(b_gpu, block=(1,1,1))

b_out = np.empty_like(b)
cuda.memcpy_dtoh(b_out, b_gpu)
print (b_out)
```

```
[1. 0. 0. ... 0. 0. 0.]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\PythonProjects\Test\CUDA\Test_PyCUDA_MemoryRelease.py", line 47, in <module>
    b_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(b.nbytes)

MemoryError: cuMemAlloc failed: out of memory
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with `free()` applied to the `DeviceAllocation` object (in this case `a_gpu`)

```
import pycuda.driver as cuda

a = np.zeros(1000000000).astype(np.float32)
a_gpu = cuda.mem_alloc(a.nbytes)
a_gpu.free()
```

From the [documentation](https://documen.tician.de/pycuda/driver.html?highlight=mem_alloc#pycuda.driver.DeviceAllocation):

> `free()`
> Release the held device memory now instead of when this object becomes unreachable. Any further use of the object is an error and will lead to undefined behavior.

Check:

```
cuda.mem_get_info()
```

Comment: Thanks.  I cannot get ```cuda.free()``` working, but it seems ```a_gpu.free()``` works

Comment: @Henry makes sense since `free()` is a method for the class ` class `pycuda.driver.DeviceAllocation`

Comment: On top of that, any way to know how much GPU memory is occupied (or how much free GPU memory is left available)?

Answer (score 0):

The device memory should be freed be deleting the device array.

`del a_gpu`